# react.js way to stop a counter after 10 iterations

Tags: reactjs

I have this code snippet to implement a counter:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
          counter: prevState.counter + 1
        }));
      }, 1000);
    }
```

And want to add a conditional that checks if the counter reached 10 and then it should stop.

Is there a React way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `this.state.counter` on each iteration:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.state.counter > 9) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        }else {
            this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
                counter: prevState.counter + 1
            }));
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```